# Powershell: Run script as administrator causes infinite execution

Tags: powershell

I am completely new to Powershell. Found a script online for updating Windows, and want to run it as administrator. Have a script that starts a new session and calls that script from a network share:

```
PowerShell.exe -noprofile -command "&{Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList 
'-noprofile -file \\path\to\networkshare\00_WindowsUpdate.ps1' -Verb RunAs}"
```

The problem is that it keeps running the script and opening new windows infinitely. I have searched the Internet and could not find anything specific to my issue. How do I run my script to call the Windows Update script once and prevent it from executing infinitely?

Comment: What's the contents of `00_WindowsUpdate.ps1`?

Comment: Line 1: 'Import-Module \\path\to\PSWindowsUpdate'
Line 2: 'Get-WUInstall -WindowsUpdate -IgnoreUserInput -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot -Verbose | Out-File C:\Windows\Temp\PSWindowsUpdate.log'

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using PowerShell, to call PowerShell, to run PowerShell?

In .cmd:

```
RUNAS /noprofile /user:domain\user "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '& \\Path\update.ps1'"
```

Comment: Tried if from cmd prompt as well, still executes infinitely and keeps opening new windows.

Comment: @PatrykChristopher That sounds like the fault of the script you're trying to run then.

Comment: That's what I was guessing. I have tried a test script where it imports a module for windows update, and then I execute a basic command that checks update history. Could it be that it is constantly importing the module?

Comment: @PatrykChristopher Can't know without source

Comment: [Windows Update](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) script. It's a bunch of different scripts where you need to import the module to make them available to use.